# No response Ajax request symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Make an ajax POST request and nothing come back:

This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "{{ path('app-like-add') }}",
        data: { imageId: id },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                $('#'+ id).removeClass('like');
                $('#'+ id).addClass("like-success");
            } else {
                alert('no :(');
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('fail');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

How calls this controller with there respective function:

```
class LikeController extends Controller {

  public function addAction(Request $request)
  {
    return new JsonResponse('success');
  }
}
```

But i get nothing, that weird thing is that i get 200 OK.

[image: Ajax Reponse]

The route is defined like this:

```
app-like-add:
pattern:               /add-like
defaults:              { _controller: AppBundle:Like:add }
```

Comment: Are you certain the url `{{ path('app-like-add') }}` is being filled? Try console logging it

Comment: Have a look at the **Response** and **Preview**  tabs in Chrome to see what response body you are actually getting.

Comment: seems your js code is not processed by twig. Put the code in a <script> tag into the twig page. Or try using the FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: Finally, i pass the url like this data-href="{{ path('app-comment-add') }}" and is OK, but still not get any reponse from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is not interpreted, have a look in the request url, you have `app-like-add`, not the equivalent url. To avoid this error, you have to put the full path or install a bundle to replace the path with the full url like `FosJsRoutingBundle` :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

This bundle allows you to expose your routing in your JavaScript code. That means you'll be able to generate URL with given parameters like you can do with the `Router` component provided in the `Symfony2` core.

In your yaml :

```
app-like-add:
    pattern:               /add-like
    defaults:              { _controller: AppBundle:Like:add }
    options:
        expose: true
```

In the JS code:

```
Routing.generate('app-like-add')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing incorrect URL, change to regular URL

```
url: "/add-like"
```